# Update sybase database in one times?

Tags: java, sql, sybase

I have a dbf file and i should update sybase database.
I did put all records from dbf file in to a singel  map which first argument in the map is value to be set in databank and the second is where condition, in this case Memo. How can i update sybase database?

```
public static void updateBcHeader( Map<String,String> list ){
    String query = "update BcHeader\n" +
            "set Label='poika' \n" +
            "where Memo like 'A'";


}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the correct code which i tested on my project.

```
        PreparedStatement stmt;
    try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement("update BcHeader set Label = ? where memo like ?");
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : list.entrySet()) {
        stmt.setString(1, entry.getKey());
        stmt.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()), Calendar.getInstance());
        stmt.setString(3, entry.getValue());
        stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You should not ignore the SQLException. And the statement should be closed in a finally block. And this code can't possibly work. You're binding 3 parameters and the query only has 2. And using a like on a Timestamp makes no sense. If you answer your own question and accept your own answer, make it at least correct.

Answer (score 3):

Loop over the map entries and execute the update statement for each entry:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = 
    connection.prepareQuery("update BcHeader set Label = ? where Memo like ?");
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entrySet : list.entries()) {
    stmt.setString(1, entry.getKey());
    stmt.setString(2, entry.getValue());
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Note that a map is really a bad choice for storing these arguments. What if you had several values to set or several elements in the where clause? What if several memos share the same label? You should use a `List<Change>`, where `Change` would be an object having a `label` and a `memo` fields.

Comment: Just a small correction:

       `PreparedStatement stmt;
     try {
      stmt = con.prepareStatement("update BcHeader set Label   = ? where memo like     ?");
      for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : list.entrySet()) {
      stmt.setString(1, entry.getKey());
   stmt.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()), Calendar.getInstance());
      stmt.setString(3, entry.getValue());
      stmt.executeUpdate();
     }
     } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     `

Comment: I left exception handling as an exercise for the reader. Ignoring exceptions like you're suggesting is a bad idea.